# Changing display to "inline"/"none" with a select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want show or hide an input by selecting an `option` in a `select` if value = 4 or 8, then show the inputs. I know that I have to work with the css (`display: "block/none"`) but my `onchange` seems to not be working. When I use radio button, it works with an `onclick`.

Here's my code:

```js
function WorkTravelControl() {
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("homeworkingselect")
      .addEventListener("change", function() {
        var value = document.getElementById("homeworking").value
        if (value === 0) {
          document.getElementById("homeworking").style.display.none
        } else {
          document.getElementById("homeworking").style.display.inline
        }
      });
  });

}
```

```html
<!-- probleme de visbilité des elements -->
<select name="homeworkingselect" value="0" onchange="WorkTravelControl()">
  <option value="0" selected></option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" ng-model="outsideluxWork.value" id="homeworking"></td>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" ng-model="outsideluxTravel.value" id="homeworking"></td>

</tr>
```

can someone help with the Javascript going with?

Comment: You cannot reach element which has no id with getElementById() methods.

Comment: You have two elements with the same id "homeworking". That is invalid HTML. Also, `HTMLElement.style.display.none` does not change a style, you want `HTMLElement..style.display = 'none'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an event handler wrapped in a function called by an inline event handler. So try getting rid of the onchange in the select and don't have window.addEventListener("load" wrapped in a function. Also add id="homeworkingselect" to your select since that is what the event listener is looking for. You are also reusing IDs, but you can't duplicate IDs.

I used a class for the text elements and looped through the text elements on change.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("homeworkingselect").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    value = e.target.value;
    homeworking = document.querySelectorAll(".homeworking");
    homeworking.forEach(function(el) {
       el.style.display = (value == 0) ? "none" : "inline";
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="homeworkingselect" id="homeworkingselect">
  <option value="0" selected></option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="outsideluxWork.value" class="homeworking">
<input type="text" ng-model="outsideluxTravel.value" class="homeworking">
```